# Is there a function that checks whether a sockaddr* named sptr points to an ipv4 or ipv6 address?

Tags: c, sockets

Is there a function that checks whether a `sockaddr *` named `sptr` points to an ipv4 or ipv6 address?
For example I have the code below, how can I add onto it to get whether the address is ipv4 or ipv6, can I use `getaddrinfo()`?

```
struct sockaddr *sptr;
struct sockaddr_in *ipv4_ptr;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the `sa_family` member:

```
switch (sptr->sa_family)
{
    case AF_INET:
    /* IPv4 */
    break;

    case AF_INET6:
    /* IPv6 */
    break;

    default:
    /* Something else */
}
```

If the `sa_family` member is `AF_INET`, that indicates an IPv4 address and the socket address is actually a `struct sockaddr_in *`.  If the `sa_family` member is `AF_INET6`, that indicates an IPv6 address and the socket address is actually a `struct sockaddr_in6`.

Answer (score 0):

The structures for `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6` address families are different, so you have to use different pointer types for them.  The way to proceed is to use:

```
struct sockaddr *genptr;
... /* initialize genptr to point to the sockaddr structure */
switch (genptr->sa_family) {
case AF_INET: {
    struct sockaddr_in *ipv4ptr = (struct sockaddr_in *)genptr;
    /* check IPV4 addresses using ipv4ptr pointer */
    } break;
case AF_INET6: {
    struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6ptr = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)genptr;
    /* check IPV6 addresses using ipv6ptr pointer */
    } break;
default: /* NEITHER IPV4 NOR IPV6, IPX? NETBIOS? X25? */
} /* switch */
```

although less efficient, you can convert your addresses with the *version agnostic* `inet_ntop(3)` routine, and use some kind of regular expression matching algorithm to partially match addresses.  `inet_ntop` routines get the generic pointer and build the ipv4/ipv6 ascii string for the network addresses in one shot.